# Доступ к произвольной строке файла

Tags: java, android, файлы

Здравствуете, столкнулся с вопросом доступа к произвольной строки в файле. Если я хочу вывести например 67000 строку ... Но не хочу бежать 1, 2, 3,..., 66999,и наконец 67000. Как можно сделать это быстрее? Например как с массивом? arr[67000]?
Слышал o RandomAccessFile, но суть не понял.

Comment: Вы не уточнили один важный момент - одинаковой ли длинны строки в Вашем файле, потому что если нет, то это невозможно.

Comment: Нет не одинаковы... Разве так сложно перейти к 800 строке например и что то там с ней сделать? Ведь смысл пробегаться по огромнейшему файлу?

Comment: К сожалению, переходить можно только к какому-то по счету байту, а не к какой-то строке. Если же есть знание о длинне всех предыдущих строк то можно вычислить к какому байту нужно перейти, в противном случае, к сожалению, необходимо будет прочитать все эти строки.

Comment: Если я просчитаю все эти строки и выберу определенную. Я ж могу её редактировать как только схочу?(ну в общем)

Comment: Если Вам нужно отредактировать конкретную строку в файле, то лучше всего читать файл построчно и так же построчно его писать, при том на нужной строчке подменив содержимое. Т.е. в итоге Вам придется прочитать всё содержимое файла и соотвественно записать всё содержимое файла. Однако если длинна строки до изменения равна длинне строки после изменения, то можно тогда обойтись лишь прочтением файла до этой строки + запись только одной этой строки.

Comment: У меня файл статический. Я его изменять не собираюсь . Там находиться база данных англ слов с переводом. (Я думал для скорости работы переходить сразу к конкретной букве когда буду искать что-либо. ОК значит я могу просчитать колличество символов на которое мне нужно сместиться. Каким методом мне переходить?

Comment: Нет другого способа попасть на нужную строку, не пройдясь по  предыдущим. Но если вдруг Вам надо будет сделать тоже самое ещё раз, то Вы можете запомнить смещения посещённых строк относительно начала файла, и во второй раз уж точно будите выходить на них быстрее file.seek(offsets[i]:)

Comment: Если информация хранится в текстовом файле такого размера, и регулярны такие операции, как произвольный доступ к строке файла по номеру - значит, пора задуматься об изменении структуры хранения. Для RO-файлов это может быть дополнительный файл-индекс смещений началов строк, например. А если содержимое файла изменяется, причём длина изменённой строки не равна исходной - то пора задуматься о переходе с плоского текста на встраиваемую СУБД...

Comment: Зачем встраиваемая СУБД, если все изменения можно писать в этот же файлик, но в конец, делая изменения только в индексе? Ох! Мы уже сами только что почти изобрели микроСУБД!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дмитрий, если вы не собираетесь менять файл и он у вас работает в роли БД, то для скорости работы 1 раз считайте файл в лист (или в мап, если вам нужна определенная буква) и им пользуйтесь.

Радо каждого слова читать файл от начала и до конца - будет очень долго (в сравнении с коллекцией). А если взять не модифицируемую коллекцию, то ещё немного в скорости выиграете (совсем чуть-чуть).

Но по каждому слову бегать по всему файлу (в 67к строк) это не то, что нужно

Comment: У меня 106 000 строк ) я понял спс

Answer (score 1):

Файл - это плоские данные, где там находятся начала строк, да и вообще, есть ли там строки текста, картинки или музыка - это неизвестно. В файле может быть все что угодно, и вероятно даже без хлеба.

Чтобы получить доступ к конкретной строке, сразу без регистрации и смс, нужно где-то и как-то узнать позицию файла, где эта строка начинается. К примеру, прочитать все строки в файле, записывая в другой файлик места, откуда эта строка начинается, а когда надо будет прочитать нужную строчку - мы читаем весь этот маленький файлик со смещениями, открываем большой файл, через RandomAccessFile переходим к нужному месте и оттуда читаем. Фактически, мы таким образом изобрели индексы, а процесс создания таких вспомогательных файликов называется индексированием.

Задача со словарем может быть решена еще проще: зная размер файла, и предварительно отсортировав слова в файле в алфавитном порядке (на самом деле в порядке кодировки, но это тонкости), можно методом половинного деления, искать позицию слова в файле приблизительно, постепенно подбираясь к нужному. Свой словарь я так и делал, разве что seek делал на 200 символов раньше, а потом читал одну строчку и отбрасывал ее, таким образом я находил начало строки. Все собираюсь победить к нем эксепшены и выложить, да времени не найду - может допишите за меня?

Comment: Было бы не плохо) отличная практика)